# FIWARE Orion CB subscription conditions

Tags: fiware-orion

Is there a way to use exceptAttrs in the attributes of the condition field in a subscription, like we can in the notification field?
For example, lets say I have an entity with attributes A,B,C,D,E and I don't want to get notified when D changes. (apart from putting only A B C E in the condition)